# Draw a corresponding schematic for a transistor layout

Tags: transistors, schematics, cmos, layout

I got the question from an exam and I did not get it right. Could someone please point out what I did wrong?

[image]

Comment: When did you take the exam?

Comment: @Andyaka Almost a year ago

Answer (score 2):

There are six transistors in the layout but only four in your schematic. Note the word **ALL** in the instructions. Two of the transistors have their gates wired so that they can never conduct, but they are transistors nonetheless.